# three.js image texture Resize message

Tags: javascript, three.js

use image Texture,

> image is not power of two (image size) Resized to 4096x2048

is shown console.

Is it possible to turn off this message ?
or
possible that do not change the size ?

Comment: I would also love to have this so that my console can be clean.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this code when you add texture

```
var Texture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('checkerboard.jpg');
    Texture.wrapS = Texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    Texture.repeat.set(4, 4);
    Texture.offset.set(0.5, 0);
```

image is not power of two (image size) Resized to 4096x2048 is warning not error also ...so you also ignore it  if you done right code

and if you really wanna remove this msg go to three js file where loadTexture function is written there is msg for console ...